# Execute js function on ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I was to set size of image which I will recive from ajax. Problem is I dont know how to fire function exacly after success.

My resize function (which work when I fire by myself from chrome dev console after ajax, but won't go automaticly after ajax ):

```
function resizePromiseImage(x) {
                x.success(function() {
                    var wW = window.innerWidth,
                         app = $('#app'),
                         picH = 0,
                         ratio = 0,
                         picW = app.find('img').width();

                     if( wW < picW ){
                         app.find('img').css({
                             'width':wW
                         });
                     }
                });
            }
```

My ajax function (which gives me image just like I want to):

```
function ajax(){
                return $.ajax({
                               url: 'http://blabla.bla/bla.php',
                               success: function(data){
                                    if(data){
                                        var url = 'http://blabla.bla/bla/'+data+'.jpg',
                                            app = $('#app');

                                        app.html('<img src="'+url+'">"');

                                    }else{
                                        $('#wrap').append('pusto');
                                    }                   
                               }
                        });
            }
```

and executing code:

```
// get a promise:
var promise = ajax();

// give a promise to other function:
resizePromiseImage(promise);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest slightly different approach:

```
function resizePromiseImage() {
  var wW = window.innerWidth,
      app = $('#app'),
      picH = 0,
      ratio = 0,
      picW = app.find('img').width();

      if( wW < picW ){
        app.find('img').css({'width':wW});
      }
});
```

... then, in the main part, just...

```
var promise = ajax();
promise.done(resizePromiseImage);
```

What you do now is trying to modify `success` property of promise itself within the callback function. It's possible (but in slightly different way: replace `x.success` with `x.done` in your code), but it make little sense.

---

But it looks like the actual problem is not about `promise` - is about resizing an image that just doesn't want to work. The problem is actually caused by delay of that image loading: when `app.find('img').width()` line is called, `<img>` element is already in the DOM... but it yet to get its true dimensions (because image is not yet here).

To work around this, you might want to use the following approach: set you resizePromiseImage as an image load handler, not the callback one. One possible approach is modifying the AJAX callback function:

```
// ...
if (data){
   var url = 'http://blabla.bla/bla/'+data+'.jpg',
       $app = $('#app'),
       $img = $('<img>').load(resizePromiseImage).attr('src', url);
   $app.empty().append($img);
}
// ...
```

With that you can modify your resizer function so no additional search for `<img>` is required:

```
function resizePromiseImage() {
   var $img = $(this),
       picW = $img.width(),
   // ...
}
```

... in other words, you'll have this image reference passed into the function as its context (`this`), and no additional look-ups (`app.find('img')`) are needed anymore. If you do this, you no longer need to call that function on `promise.done`.

Comment: is everything ok in your different approach to fn resizePromiseImage() ? Looking for ending of that code block, I think u're missing some code

Comment: Yes, I cut it, as it wasn't actually relevant. My point is that you won't have to augment the promise object when you can pass the function to its `done` method.

Comment: Still not workin with var promise = ajax();                  promise.done(resizeImage()); (resizeImage() == without x.done in body )

Comment: `promise.done(resizeImage)`, without parenthesis - you pass the function itself, not its result.

Comment: Without parenthesis: var promise = ajax();promise.done(resizeImage); And still when I execute them, image is not resizing. When after that two commands I use just resizeImage() from console, voila, its working :<

Comment: Sorry, I was too concentrated on that `promise` stuff, having completely forgot its purpose. See, in that function you're trying to check width of an image when it's most probably not loaded yet (it's easy to check; just add `console.log(picW);` should be equal to 0). To prevent it, you should actually attempt to resize on that image `load` event fired.

Comment: Yea, console.log() shows picW == 0. Could you tell me exacly where should I link that resize? I dont get idea when image load event is going on. Thank you very much for your concern

Comment: Yes, I updated the question with an answer. BTW, that's the lesson for both of us, I suppose: I should've checked the _content_ of your question more thoroughly, and you should've described the problem you actually had instead of the problem you tried to solve. ) But that's OK.

Comment: You are right. Now everything is fine. I didn't know I can use .load() and it will solve my problem. That means 2 lessons learned. Thanky! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming x.success to x.done.

According to jQuery documentation:

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and
>   jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare
>   your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(),
>   and jqXHR.always() instead.

Comment: I've changed x.success to x.done (or even x.always) and still nothing happens

Comment: just: Viewport target-densitydpi is not supported